# Hide iframe using jquery .hide

Tags: jquery, css

I am creating an iframe from a bookmarklet. The iframe has `id='contentIframe'`

I want to be able to hide the iframe from within so i'm using the following html & jquery code:

```
<button id="hide">hide</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hide").click(function() {
        $("#contentIframe").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

But when I click the button it simply does nothing.

Also, when the iframe loads it loads from a css file so the surround of the inner html is a class named modal... if I inspect this class in say Chrome and manually set `display:none;` this hides the iframe and this is actually a preferable solution for a couple of resons so i try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hide").click(function() {
        $(".modal").hide();
    });
});
</script>
```

This also has no effect when clicking the button... Any ideas?

NOTE: I only have control of the iframe, not the outer page as the iframe is used to collect data from the page a user is viewing

Comment: You are asking for a script located in the page embedded in the iframe to access the DOM of the outer page?

Comment: put alert("hi") before the hide() function and click on #hide - see if it alerts you

Comment: I believe the question is can the embedded page access the DOM of it's parent to hide itself

Comment: @thatidiotguy That's correct - I only have control of the iframe, not the outer page as the iframe is used to collect data from the page a user is viewing

Answer (score 4):

try this in your click event:

```
$('#contentIframe', window.parent.document).hide();
```

Like so:

Parent web page html:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe id="contentIframe" src="frame.htm"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

frame.htm:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body style="background-color:red;">
        <button id="hide">hide</button>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#hide").click(function() {
                    $('#contentIframe', window.parent.document).hide();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This assumes the parent web page and frame web page are both served from the same domain...

Comment: hmm i did a quick test and it seemed to work, will update my answer with full code

Comment: I only have control of the iframe, not the outer page as the iframe is used to collect data from the page a user is viewing - sorry, should have said that in OP, will amend - many thanks for your help

Comment: that shouldn't matter, as long as you can select the iframe with jQuery.  Are both pages served from the same domain?

Comment: No, they are not from the same domain, the iframe must be closed from within without interaction with the parent if possible.

Comment: if you don't have control over the parent window then you're pretty screwed i think - might be worth checking out this for some tips on cross-domain iFrame use: http://blog.cakemail.com/the-iframe-cross-domain-policy-problem/

Answer (score 0):

The code you listed is running inside the iFrame (i think).  As such, it cannot see the DOM of the outer page, and so has no visibility of contentIFrame or .modal

I believe that a script in the outer page can reference elements inside the iFrame, so you could try moving the code to the outer page...

Comment: That's right...I only have control of the iframe, not the outer page as the iframe is used to collect data from the page a user is viewing