# Trig an click event out of an iframe with jquery

Tags: jquery, iframe, onclick

I have an iframe in my site and want to trig a click event outside of the iframe.
The iframe is loaded as a lightbox and there is a form in the iframe and i want to close the lightbox at submit.

I use this code but the click event does not work. When I run the same code in the firebug the lightbox close successfully, but here I get no result.

```
$('iframe', parent.document)
    .parent('div#pp_full_res .pp_pic_holder')
    .siblings('div.pp_details')
    .find('a.pp_close')
    .click();
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider calling a function in the parent frame instead. Provided that the document inside the iframe adheres to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), the following is possible:

```
window.parent.closeLightbox();
```

The `closeLightbox()` function should then contain the code you have tested in Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

actions inside an iframe cannot execute scripts in the parent window, or access the parent DOM

edit: take a look at [Hide iframe using jquery .hide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498437/hide-iframe-using-jquery-hide/12498547#comment16818932_12498547)